# In Wordpress AMP post read more functionality

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I have Accelerated Mobile Pages plugin I want read more functionality on post detail page for AMP pages

Comment: Hello @Vikrant Magare, welcome to StackOverflow.  Your question is vague/not clear.  Can you be more specific? Perhaps provide code samples (if relevant)?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).  Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).